# ContentControl Content Property not changing with hosted content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to learn MVVM and have come across a weird snag. I have a main menu with a drawer control that comes out and shows a menu:
[image]

In the main window where this drawer is, I have a `ContentControl` where I set its content with a Binding.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MainWindowContentControl" Content="{Binding Path=WindowContent}"/>
```

This window's binding is set to a view model.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

and here is the ViewModel:

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: ViewModelBase
{

    private object _content;

    public object WindowContent
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(WindowContent));
        }
    }
    public ICommand SetWindowContent { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SetWindowContent = new ChangeWindowContentCommand(this);
    }


}
```

So far up to this point, everything works fine. So for example, if I click "Recovery Operations", I get this:

**RecoveryOperationsView.xaml**
[image]

In "**RecoveryOperationsView.xaml**" (which is a `UserControl`) I also reference the view model from above like so..

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

and have a button to call the command to change the Content property of the `ContentControl` from the main window..

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Restore Database" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Command="{Binding SetWindowContent}" CommandParameter="DatabaseRecovery" >
```

In my class to process the commands, I change  the content based off of the passed parameter using a switch statement like so

**ChangeWindowContentCommand.cs**

```
public class ChangeWindowContentCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindowViewModel viewModel;
    public ChangeWindowContentCommand(MainWindowViewModel vm)
    {
        this.viewModel = vm;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "Home":
                viewModel.WindowContent = new HomeView();
                break;
            case "RecoveryOps":
                viewModel.WindowContent = new RecoveryOperationsView();
                break;
            case "DatabaseRecovery":
                viewModel.WindowContent = new DatabaseRestoreView();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is where I get lost... If I click something within this new window, say "Restore Database" and inspect it with a breakpoint, I can see the property being changed but the actual `ContentControl` Content property doesnt change to the new `UserControl` I made... I can change the content with anything in the drawer, but if I try to click a button in the hosted Content of the `ContentControl` nothing changes. What am I missing?

Comment: "_I can see the property being changed but the actual window content doesn't_". Changed to what? Are you perhaps by accident creating a duplicate MainWindowViewModel somewhere? "_but if I try to use anything in the hosted content of the ContentControl, nothing works_" What is that "anything"? I have no idea what you mean with this sentence. Please edit and improve your question to clarify this.

Comment: @elgonzo I've updated my question with as much clarification I could get. I don't think I am making multiple references to the MainWindowViewModel anywhere unless adding the datacontext in XAML does exactly that... In the breakpoint, when I click the "Restore Database" button, I can see the WindowContent property changing to an instance of DatabaseRestoreView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to be 100% sure without having your project to test with, but I am fairly confident that at least one of the issues is that your `UserControl` and your `MainWindow` use different instances of the `MainWindowViewModel`. You do not need to instantiate the VM for the user control, as it will inherit the `DataContext` from the `MainWindow`. The way it works in WPF is that if any given `UIElement` does *not* have the`DataContext` assigned explicitly, it will inherit it from the first element up the logical tree that does has one assigned.

So, just delete this code, and it should solve at least that issue.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And since you're learning WPF, I feel obligated to provide a couple other tips. Even though you're using a ViewModel, you are still mixing UI and logic by creating a very specific implementation of `ICommand` and assigning a UI element through your ViewModel. This breaks the MVVM pattern. I know MVVM takes a little time to understand, but once you do, it is very easy to use and maintain.

To solve your problem, I would suggest creating View Models for each of your user controls. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844523/7159784), where I go into quite a bit of detail on the implementation.

For switching the different views, you have a couple of options. You can either use a `TabControl`, or if you want to use a command, you can have a single `ContentControl` bound to a property of `MainWindowViewModel` that is of type `ViewModelBase`. Let's call it `CurrentViewModel`. Then when the command fires, you assign the view model of the desired user control to that bound property. You will also need to utilize [implicit data templates](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_wpf_data_templates.htm). The basic idea is that you create a template for each of the user control VM types, which would just contains an instance of the Views. When you assign the user control VM to the `CurrentViewModel` property, the binding will find those data templates and render the user control.  For example:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type viewmodels:RecoveryOperationsViewModel}">
    <views:RecoveryOperationsView/>
  </DataTemplate> 
  <!-- Now add a template for each of the views-->
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl x:Name="MainWindowContentControl" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
```

See how this approach keeps UI and logic at an arm's length?

And lastly, consider creating a very generic implementation of `ICommand` to use in all your ViewModels rather than many specific implementations. I think most WPF programmers have more or less this exact [RelayCommand implementation](https://gist.github.com/schuster-rainer/2648922) in their arsenal.

Comment: This was absolutely the issue! I really appreciate the help and the excellent explanation of de-coupling my viewmodels from my views! My approach was much like the one you suggested of the two where I create a ViewModel for every user control. I guess its the implementation of switching between them that i need to work on. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helped. It looks like you're almost there, just a small change in concept. You should use the implicit data templates as above and move the switching code into your MainViewModel (rather than ICommand class), while using the generic implementation of RelayCommand above. That will perfectly adhere to the MVVM pattern!

Comment: So I implemented the DataTemplate method you provided using an exposed property `public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel` to change the current view, however, when I try to click a button in one of the views that appear in the UserControl, it appears as though the inherited DataContext is lost up the VisualTree.It looks like the output console logs the following: 

` BindingExpression path error: 'ChangeCurrentViewModel' property not found on 'object' ''RecoveryOperationsViewModel' (HashCode=58033516)'.

Is this because setting the `CurrentViewModel` changes the context for the view?

Comment: So the way that will work, is the user controls will no longer inherit the data context from the window, but rather from the `ContentControl` due to the binding. This `DataContext` will now be `RecoveryOperationsViewModel` rather than `MainWindowViewModel`, where the command is defined. Hence the binding error. You should be able to use `RelativeSource` binding to fire the command. Or move the command to the child view model, and have the child communicate with parent VM. Not sure how much this makes sense, but I can flesh this out in my answer for you after work today.

Comment: One simple concept that helped me A LOT when I was first learning WPF is: **Everything is a tree**! And everything inherits from up the logic tree. This applies to styles, data templates, and any other dependency property. To skip some levels in the logical tree (i.e. to select the correct datacontext), you would generally use `RelativeSource` binding (among other techniques).

Comment: So, I used the following in my `RecoveryOperationsView`

`<UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>`

To try to find the datacontext of its logical parent. Not sure if this is a proper way of doing it but it seems to be working!

Comment: You don't really want to do that, as the data context is already assigned to the user control in your main view, so that will cause other binding issues. I meant Relative Source Binding for the commands. i.e. `Command="{Binding SetWindowContent, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183986/discussion-between-ephtee-and-nik).