# How to pass data from MainWindow to a User Control that's inside the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I did my research that people tend to use ViewModel to achieve this but I am sort of stuck in it.

I have a

`public ObservableCollection<Order> orderList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Order>();`

in `MainWindow` which is already filled up with data.

in MainWindow XAML I have a User Control inside the `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabCollection">
        <TabItem Header="UC1">
            <local:UserControl1/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="UC2">
            <local:UserControl2/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

We only talk about UC1 here so in UC1 XAML here I have a `ListView` inside:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:UserControl1VM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ListView x:Name="ListViewText">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Lastname}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Order" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ordername}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Delivery time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Deliverytime}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Phone Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And here's the code in UserControl1VM.cs:

```
namespace QuickShop
{
class UserControl1VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Order> orderList;
    public ObservableCollection<Order> OrderList
    {
        get { return orderList; }
        set
        {
            orderList = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OrderList"));
        }
    }

    //
    private void FindDeliveryOrders(IEnumerable<Order> sortList)
    {
        foreach (var order in sortList)
        {
            if (order.Delivery.Equals("Yes"))
            {
                //deliveryOrders.Add(order);
                this.ListViewText.Items.Add(new Order { Firstname = order.Firstname, Lastname = order.Lastname, Ordername = order.Ordername, Deliverytime = order.Deliverytime, Phone = order.Phone, Address = order.Address, Email = order.Email });
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
}
```

And Of course these are incomplete codes because I don't know how to proceed next.

My goal is just to populate the `ListView` and it will automatically update itself if `orderList` changes. But right now I couldn't even know whether the ViewModel is working or not, any thoughts and code demo would be very grateful.

Comment: No need to take `public ObservableCollection<Order> orderList` in `MainWindow`. Define and implement it in `UserControl1VM `.

Comment: @GaurangDave but by doing so I have to move the entire method that populates the `orderList` into `UserControl1VM`

Comment: That is correct! I think that will be a proper implementation of MVVM. You need to separate the related VM to its View.

Comment: @GaurangDave Then why would I need ViewModel I can just implement it in that auto-generated UserControl1.xaml.cs (because that method is calling SQL Database to read data and populate `orderList` so it's somewhat independent)

Comment: Usercontrol will display a list then according to me the best structure will be that you connect sql in usercontrol and perform all user control related operations there.  Look this is programming, you can achieve any task using any flow and structure but once your application will grow, you may find it difficult to manage the code changes.

Comment: @GaurangDave I know I just wanna make it a proper MVVM style. so is that still considered as MVVM implementation?

Comment: This is one of the many things that Dependency Injection is designed to solve. In a "real" MVVM app your tab control's ItemSource would bind to a list of TabControlVM (say) which allows your view model layer to both monitor and control which tab is currently active (trust me, you'll need this sooner or later, and you don't want to start fudging stuff like this with things like behaviors etc). Then, instead of passing your order list all over the place and referencing up and down the visual tree in XAML you instead let the DI framework inject it directly into whatever view models need it.

Comment: Have a look at these two answers. Hopefully that will lead you to some ideas. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844523/7159784) and another approach with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385848/7159784).

Comment: @Nik that even more confuses me. a working example will help me better.

Comment: Is there a canonical explanation of this by Microsoft - to me this was not entirely intuitive, but then I haven't read the framework documents cover to cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UserControl should never have a "private" view model, as you assign it to the DataContext in the UserControl's XAML. It should instead expose dependency properties that could be bound to properties of an externally provided view model object.

Declare an `ItemsSource` property like this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl1));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And bind the ListView like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    ...
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        ...
    </ListView>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

When you use the UserControl, bind the property to a view model property:

```
<TabItem Header="UC1">
    <local:UserControl1 ItemsSource="{Binding OrderList}"/>
</TabItem>
```

The last XAML snippet assumes that the object in the UserControl's DataContext has a `OrderList` property. This would automatically happen when the TabControl is bound to a collection of view model objects with that property.

---

**Alternatively**, let the elements in the UserControl's XAML directly bind to the properties of the object in the inherited DataContext.

```
<UserControl ...>
    ...
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OrderList}">
        ...
    </ListView>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Your control would not have to expose additional bindable properties, but it would only work with DataContext objects that actually provide the expected source properties.