# How to set DataBinding for UserControl with ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with couple of controls inside. So I decide to use ViewModel to do managing for all those bindable value. But I find my binding is always null. So how to setup binding for ViewModel in usercontrol

MainWindows.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <cus:Wizard WizardModel="{Binding MyModel}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
   public MainWindow()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
   }
}
```

ViewModel.cs(MainWindow viewmodel)

```cs
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Model _MyModel;
        public Model MyModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyModel;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyModel = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyModel");
            }
        }
    }
```

Wizard.xaml(my UserControl)

```
<UserControl mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Something}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Wizard.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Wizard : UserControl
{
    private readonly object modelLock = new object();
    private Model CurrentModel = new Model();
    public Wizard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = CurrentModel;
    }     
    public Model WizardModel
    {
        get { return (Model)this.GetValue(WizardModelProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(WizardModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WizardModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WizardModel", typeof(Model), typeof(Wizard), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ModelChanged)));
    private static void ModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Wizard)d).OnModelChanged();
    }
    private void OnModelChanged()
    {
        lock (this.modelLock)
        {
            if(CurrentModel != null)
            {
                CurrentModel = null;
            }
            if (WizardModel != null)
            {
                CurrentModel = WizardModel;                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The WizardModel in UserControl is always null. So how to setup this ViewModel in UserControl

Comment: `<cus:Wizard DataContext="{Binding MyModel}"/>`

Comment: A UserControl should typically not have its own, "private" view model. It should never explicitly set its own DataContext, but instead operate on the DataContext that it inherits from its parent element, e.g. the MainWindow. The most flexible approach is to make it completely independent of any particular view model class, by exposing (bindable) dependency properties, as shown e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53480682/1136211

Comment: @AbinMathew This works, but this make my WizardModel useless

Comment: Your WizardModel is useless by design. However, to answer you actual question, `WizardModel="{Binding MyModel}"` expects the MyModel property in the current DataContext, which you have explicitly set to CurrentModel. It just won't work. You must never explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl, otherwise any standard, DataContext-based Bindings won't work anymore.

Comment: @Clemens This may work with one binding right? Assume I have multiple Textbox and all of them is bindable, can they be update also?

Comment: Expose one dependency property per TextBox, or directly operate on (i.e. bind to properties of) the inherited DataContext.

Comment: As a note, `lock (this.modelLock)` is also pointless. The PropertyChanged callback of a dependency property is only called in one thread, i.e. the one in which the DependencyObject was created. You can drop the whole code behind of your UserControl, except the InitializeComponent call in its constructor. The rest is useless.

Comment: @Clemens when you said inherited DataContext, is it <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding WizardModel.Something, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />? Or you think get rid of WizardModel is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UserControl that is supposed to operate on a particular view model class - or more precisely on a class with a particular set of public properties - may directly bind to the view model properties in its XAML.

Given a view model like

```
public class Model
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

you may write a UserControl with nothing more than this XAML

```
<UserControl ...>
    ...
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Something}" />
    ...
</UserControl>
```

and this code behind

```
public partial class Wizard : UserControl
{
    public Wizard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }  
}
```

If you now set its DataContext to an instance of `Model` (or any other class with a `Something` property), it will just work:

```
<local:Wizard DataContext="{Binding MyModel}"/>
```

Since the value of the DataContext property is inherited from parent to child elements, this will also work:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding MyModel}">
    <local:Wizard/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

However, the UserControl still dependends on the existence of a `Something` property in its DataContext. In order to get rid of this dependence, your control may expose a dependency property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyText), typeof(string), typeof(Wizard));

public string MyText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
}
```

and bind the element in its XAML to its own property

```
<UserControl ...>
    ...
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Now you would bind the control's property instead of setting its DataContext:

```
<local:Wizard MyText="{Binding MyModel.Something, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```